# JQPLOT bar graph range

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I have created a dynamic bar graph using jqplot, the problem is that some values are quite big i.e. 10000000 and others are pretty small i.e. 2000 or 10000. Because of this range issue, i am only able to see the bigger valued graphs while the rest dont even appear up or appear as just a line on the axis.

Could someone please let me know how this range issue could be solved?

Comment: Using a logarithmic scale?

Comment: You have a bar which is 5000 times smaller than the other one. It's size is negligible compared to the bigger bar. Just for the demonstration, If the larger bar was 1 meter long, the smaller one was only 0.02 centimeters long... You understand that mathematically, the representation of the smaller bar is indeed a line on the axis. [Graph tip - Don't use a log scale on a bar graph!](http://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/1477/)

Comment: Yes Alon_A, I understand why it's coming up as a line on the axis. But considering that i have to display some form of information, don't you think i should not be displaying it as a line on the axis. I was thinking if there might be a way to still display the smaller value bars somehow

Comment: I want to achieve this using JQPLOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment, and your need to achieve a solution which includes jqplot bar chart, i'll suggest illustrating the massive difference of values by adding a second line graph to the plot.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var data = [10000000, 5000000,10000,2000];
var options= {    
   title: 'Bar and Line Chart',      
   series:[{
      renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,                 
      rendererOptions: {          
         barMargin: 5,           
         fillToZero: true               
      },
      pointLabels: {
         show: true,
         seriesLabelIndex:1,
         hideZeros:false
      }
   }],
   axes: {      
      xaxis: {          
         tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
         renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
      },      
      yaxis: {   
         labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
         padMin: 0,
         pad: 1.1,
         label: ' logarithmic scale',
         rendererOptions: { forceTickAt0: true}
      } 
   },               
};  
$.jqplot('graph', [data,data], options );
});
```

Here is a working solution in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alon_A/f5g6tg28/2/)

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a lot. I would still like to know if jqplot provides a way of doing this without having a line chart created. Is there a way with which i could achieve scaling??

Comment: @Farhan you cannot scale the y axis, [but this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851806/jqplot-y-axis-scaling)

Comment: This wont work since the range is quite big and also the difference is quite huge between the values.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Farhan You're welcome, I don't see a way of achieving the goal using `jqplot` and only a bar chart. Anyway, If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it (by the little _V_ sign next to the answer's score). Thanks :)